# assning the first column of the file to hash key and the rest to hash value

Tags: perl

i have a file as follows:

```
23  Line number 23
2   Line number 2
87  Line number 87
28  Line number 28
4   Line number 4
83  Line number 83
```

i need to take the first column as hash keys and second as hash value.
Also i should sort the file using the hash keys

Comment: Please format the Question correctly, it is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy: We `split` the line at whitespace into two pieces. The first part is the `$key`, the rest is the `$value`.

We then sort the `keys` of the `%hash` alphabetically, and print out all the data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my %hash;
while (<>) {
  chomp; # remove newline
  my ($key, $value) = split ' ', $_, 2;
  $hash{$key} = $value;
}
# or shorter:
# my %hash = map {chomp; split ' ', $_, 2} <>;

my @sorted_keys = sort keys %hash;
for my $key (@sorted_keys) {
  print "$key $hash{$key}\n";
}
# or shorter:
# print "$_ $hash{$_}\n" for sort keys %hash;
```

The input can be provided via STDIN or as a file named in a command line argument.

Output for the input you provided:

```
2 Line number 2
23 Line number 23
28 Line number 28
4 Line number 4
83 Line number 83
87 Line number 87
```

If you want numerical sorting, change `sort keys` to `sort {$a <=> $b} keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/perl/bin  -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file_name = "file.txt";
open(FH, "<".$file_name) or die "Could not open $file_name";
my %hash = ();
while(<FH>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $value) = split(/ /, $_);
    $hash{$key} = $value;
}

close FH;

print Dumper(%hash);
```

Comment: What does `@garb` do? What is `slipt`?